# GWT RequestFactory: getting "No type for token ..." Exception

Tags: gwt-rpc, requestfactory

I'm new to GWT and RequestFactory so I'm coding a simple test app using GWT RequestFactory for RPC and Objectify for ORM.

I have a simple Person entity and was able to get all crud operations working fine.  I wanted to try adding a value type for storing addresses as an @Embedded property in my Person class, just like it's shown on the Google Developer site.  So I added a simple POJO Address, AddressProxy extending ValueProxy, etc.

I end up having adding a couple of lines of code to my RequestFactory call like this:

```
PersonRequest req = rf.personRequest();
AddressProxy address = req.create(AddressProxy.class);  // Added this
address.setCity(city);                                  // this
PersonProxy person = req.create(PersonProxy.class);
person.setName("Joe");
person.setPhone("215-555-1212");
person.setAddress(address);                             // and this.
req.save(person).fire();
```

So everything compiles perfectly and stepping through the code everything is A-OK on client side.  On the server side, I get UnexpectedExcpetion: No type for token...

Spefically it seems to get caught on this method here under com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ResolverServiceLayer:

```
@Override
public Class<? extends BaseProxy> resolveClass(String typeToken) {
  String deobfuscated = deobfuscator.getTypeFromToken(typeToken);
  if (deobfuscated == null) {
    die(null, "No type for token %s", typeToken);
  }
```

I'm assuming it's trying to determine the type from the request context but it's not helping me see what is missing on my end.  What would cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post from Thomas Broyer the [Google Web Toolkit](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/9CwPza-kIfI) Google Group solved the issue.  Here's a quote:

> Annotation processing in Eclipse a barely usable. I battled for hours yesterday to make it refresh the generated DeobfuscatorBuilder. IIRC, I refresh the project in eclipse, then restarted it, then disabled annotation processing, deleted the .apt_generated folder and re-enabled annotation processing. If you can use Maven for your project, then I'd bet it works much better there! (I had the issue on the gwt-user project itself, so it wasn't an option for me) Next time, I'll try setting up a build action (or whatever) to run "javac -proc:only" instead of relying of Eclipse's built-in (and awfully buggy) APT.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the needed `with()`.

Try something like `req.save(person).with("address").fire();`

Comment: That doesn't work and I don't think it wouldn't apply anyway.  with() is used for retrieving entities that have a key value stored that establishes a relationship with other entity types (Haven't gotten to that point yet, but its next on my test list).

Comment: Well that was my only idea... I lost a lot of time looking out for this `with()`instruction, so I thought it might have been the same. Hopefully someone will have a better answer!

Comment: I take back what I said earlier.  I just noticed an example of a persist method that used .with() [here link](http://code.google.com/p/listwidget/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/turbomanage/listwidget/client/mvp/EditListActivity.java). However, as I said before, that did not resolve my problem.

Comment: I got my test working with @Embedded fields. Contrary to my misguided belief, .with() was required as you suggested earlier.